# Calling EditorDriver.setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) does nothing

Tags: java, gwt

Using GWT 2.5.

I have got a few separate beans and editors classes (I use SimpleBeanEditorDriver).

EditorDriver1 edits Bean1 instance, EditorDriver2 edits Bean2, EditorDriver3 edits Bean3, etc.

Bean1 class exposes a few non-primitive fields, among which one Bean2 and one Bean3 instance (but it does not really matter here, at least I don't think it should).

When I call EditorDriver.setConstraintViolations method on EditorDriver1 or EditorDriver2 (I call it on EditorDriver1 *then* on EditorDriver2, but - sorry I'm repeating myself :) - I don't think it should matter at all), all is fine. Errors are displayed onscreen. If I call getErrors() just after setConstraintViolations(), I can see the errors are there.
When I do the same for EditorDriver3 (I do it in the same order: after EditorDriver1 and EditorDriver3), getErrors() returns an empty list after setConstraintViolations().

I have tried debugging this for a while, comparing the ConstraintViolation, EditorDriver, delegate maps objects but I could not spot any meaningful difference between them, which would explain the different behavior.
Just in case, I have also checked GWT's Github issues but couldn't find anything similar enough to this problem.

Any idea about things to look out for, things to test for or particular clues to search for while debugging ?
Thank you.

One thing I have noticed is that, if I forge the ConstraintViolation objects myself (instead of getting them from a Validator's validate method), it works.
The only difference I can see in the ConstraintViolation is that the ConstraintViolation I forge have both desc and elementType null (instead of some reference to a validator, and FIELD, respectively).

Comment: Without seeing any code at all, it is hard to be too specific, but Editors by themselves don't handle errors unless they happen to implement `HasEditorErrors` (like gxt's fields or `ValueBoxEditorDecorator`. The fact that you can forge a violation and it works suggests that you have the editors right at least... But if you decide to debug, SimpleViolation#iterableFromConstrantViolations and #pushViolations are the two methods to dig into, to make sure the violation is translated correctly into an error, and is passed down to the delegates, then ErrorCollector to draw them all.

Comment: Unfortunately I might not be able to find much more time to dig into it, but I will keep the advice in mind if I can free up enough time (would be nice to figure what was wrong...), thank you.

Comment: If you can share more code, or at least enough that demonstrates the issue, I'm sure people like myself would be happy to dig in as well.

Comment: I have found the cause, mostly by luck. Editor1 is made of multiple private editors (E1A, E1B etc.) and provides direct access to E1A/E1B values via (public or package protected) getters. Depending on the order of my getters in Editor1 (where they appear in the source file !), I get different behavior. If a LeafValueEditor is followed by a HasEditorError, this HasEditorError won't be notified of the error.

The order does have a influence on the transient generated types code (it produces a different output), but I think I will have to try to produce a minimal test case to isolate the issue.